# How to Automate Enable/Disable user in AD via PowerShell from CSV with date parameter

Tags: powershell, date, active-directory

I started learn scripting in PS and I want to automate Enable/Disable users in AD from csv file with specific date, but I need to a little help. I have first question about Enable, how can I set the date when user must be enabled? Need I create this attribute or I can write it somewhere in the script something like that?

Comment: There's no mechanism in AD for enabling an account _after_ a certain date - you'll have to create a scheduled task to run `Enabled-ADAccount` or `Set-ADUser` on the date when they're supposed to be enabled

Answer (score 0):

You need  to create a basic task in task scheduler and trigger as daily and action as start program and specify your PowerShell script.

The powershell script to enable users on a specific date is :
If you want to enable all users in the CSV file on a same date, please use below script :

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$a = [DateTime] "9/9/2021"
$b = (Get-Date).ToString('M/d/y')
if ( $a -eq $b) {
    Import-Csv "path-to-csv-file" | ForEach-Object {
        $samAccountName = $_."samAccountName"
        Get-ADUser -Identity $samAccountName | Enable-ADAccount
        Write-Host "-User "$samAccountName" Enabled"
    }
}
```

If the enabled date for each user is specified in the CSV file, please use below script :

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$b = (Get-Date).ToString('M/d/y')
Import-Csv "path-to-csv-file" | ForEach-Object {
    $samAccountName = $_."samAccountName"     
    $date = $_."date"
    if ( $date -eq $b) {
        Get-ADUser -Identity $samAccountName | Enable-ADAccount
        Write-Host "-User "$samAccountName" Enabled"
    }
}
```

Similar way, you can implement for the disabled users.

These scripts will be running daily by task scheduler. If the date provided in the script is equal to the date on which the script is running, the user account will be enabled/disabled.

**Reference** :

https://active-directory-wp.com/docs/Usage/How_to_add_a_cron_job_on_Windows/Scheduled_tasks_and_cron_jobs_on_Windows/

Comment: Many thanks, I thinking about something like this today morning :D, I can to do same thing in one script when I want to disabled user from csv  ? 
One CSV file with First and last name, SamAccountName, DateDisable, DateEnabled - and one script for this ? Or I need to do something else ?
Thanks for clues, I try to write some code, I want in the future add some functions with logs and reports :D But first I need basic script

Comment: PS: How can I import csv file from teams by powershell ?

Comment: You can use the single script to enable and disable users. You can add the logic for TodayDate = DateDisabled, disable the user and TodayDate = dateEnabled, enable the user

Comment: For importing csv from teams, it will be similar to this :
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/powershell-script-to-export-microsoft-teams-usage-in-csv-format/m-p/484713

Comment: I use this script but I don't know how to import date from csv (How to format date) ?
I use this format in CSV file 9/28/2021 (M,d,y) How I need to import this to powershell thanks for some clues

Comment: Please check this link to format the date in CSV : https://admin.echo360.com/hc/en-us/articles/360035034372-Formatting-Dates-for-CSV-Imports#:~:text=Some%20of%20the%20CSV%20imports%20contain%20date%20fields%2C,files%20using%20a%20spreadsheet%20program%20like%20Microsoft%C2%AE%20Excel.

Comment: I did this by myself thanks for help and I try now to download my csv file from SharePoint by Get-PnPFile

Answer (score 0):

I have something like that.

```
Get-Date #download date from the system

$b = (Get-Date).ToString('M"/"d"/"yyyy') #convert the date from the system to my csv format which is 9/9/2021

Write-Host $b #check date format

Import-Csv "C:\it\blokady\Accounts Deactivation Test.csv" | ForEach-Object {

$SamAccountName = $_."SamAccountName"     

$dateDisable = $_."dateDisable"


 Write-Host $dateDisable

if ( $dateDisable -eq $b) {
    
    Get-ADUser -Identity $SamAccountName | Disable-ADAccount
    
    Write-Host "-User "$SamAccountName" Disabled"
}

$dateEnable = $_."dateEnable"
 
 if ( $dateEnable -eq $b) {
    
    Get-ADUser -Identity $SamAccountName | Enable-ADAccount
    
    Write-Host "-User "$SamAccountName" Enable"
}

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).